# how to ensure the execution sequence of threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

In a multi-threaded application, we start multiple threads. We allow the threads to execute in a random order except in one of the function calls, we need to ensure the execution sequence. How to do it in C#?

Comment: What criteria are you going to use to order your threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure on the most correct way to approach this case, since threads are naturally asynchronous.

But the easiest hack I would use is concurrency control.
Say you have 3 threads T1, T2, and T3, and 3 mutexes M1, M2 and M3. Whenever you need to start executing them on sequence, use the mutexes to create a some sort of chainlock:

T1 acquires M1 lock
T2 acquires M2 lock and waits for M1 to be released
T3 acquires M3 lock and waits for M1 and M2 to be released.

When a thread is done with its part of that task, then release it's lock.

And so on with more threads.

Hope it helps.